JAVA_HOME environment variable missing /bin at the end in ubuntu github actions runner
I am trying to run an application that needs Java as a prerequisite on a github actions runner. My yaml script is like:
steps:
  .
  .
  - name: Setup Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v2
    with:
      distribution: 'adopt'
      java-version: '21'
  .
  .
  - name: Step that needs Java
    uses: ...
    with:
      ...

The Java setup goes fine, but the step that needs Java fails with an error saying
ERROR: The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. JAVA_HOME is set to /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/21.0.4-7.0.LTS/x64 and it does not exist.
The correct path is /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/21.0.4-7.0.LTS/x64/bin What do I do to append /bin to the end of JAVA_HOME?

You're using a fairly old version of the action. Does this issue occur if you use actions/setup-java@v4? I don't think action v2 supports your java-version.

The issue occurs with actions/setup-java@v4 too

Your setup is correct. JAVA_HOME is also correct. If you run just the setup action actions/setup-java@v2, java is setup correctly and $JAVA_HOME/bin is in the PATH.
The issue is most likely with the steps that follow java setup in your workflow.
This workflow proves it:
name: java

on:
  workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  java:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Setup Java
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        distribution: 'adopt'
        java-version: '21'

    - name: Show java
      run: |
        echo $JAVA_HOME
        echo $PATH
        java -version

The output of the "Show java" step is like this:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/21.0.4-7.0.LTS/x64

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/21.0.4-7.0.LTS/x64/bin:/snap/bin:/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)


I don't do anything in the intermediate steps that fiddle with JAVA_HOME. In your example too, echo $JAVA_HOME outputs the value without /bin at the end, whereas java, javac, and all else of importance are within /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/21.0.4-7.0.LTS/x64/bin

HAVA_HOME has to point to the directory that contains bin and other subdirectories. Then $JAVA_HOME/bin has to be added to the PATH environment variable in order to java to be runnable from anywhere. As you can is in the workflow run, I was able to invoke java compiler.

What do I do to resolve the failing step then? Any ideas?

Please show the steps that follow setup-java.

I just moved my Setup Java step to just before Step that needs Java, and it throws the same issue.

Perhaps the step that uses java should not be looking inside $JAVA_HOME but instead inside $JAVA_HOME/bin. If you show the step that is failing, I can try to address the issue.
